Messed up a SOL transfer. Tried to recover using Wormhole and failed again. Can someone help to retrieve tokens?
Messed up a SOL transfer by using a wrong network. Tried to recover it using wormhole bridge and was able to see the tokens in wallets. Tried to recover it for a while in 2022 and failed again. Now I need to trace this and recover these tokens. Can you help? thank you in advance.
